# Selenium Framework(finding the field name)

Tags: selenium

I am trying to find the field name "SavePLButton". The Html code behind this page is:

```
<ul class="button-bar">
<li class="first">
<a href="#" id="SavePLButton" type="button" name="SavePLButton" value="Save"  onclick="formSubmit('SAVEEXIT');">
<i class="icon-save"/>
Save
</a>
</li>
```

The C# code that I am using is:

```
 var Submit = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.CssSelector("i.icon-save"));
 Submit.Click();
```

I have also tried:

```
var Submit = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("SavePLButton"));
Submit.Click();
```

It is unable to find the fieldname. Can someone please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until element visible as below :-

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

var Submit = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("SavePLButton")));
 Submit.Click();
```

**Note** :- make sure before try this element is not inside any `frame`

Hope it helps.....:)